# Accessing pcap file header

Tags: c, networking, pcap, libpcap

Is there any function for retrieving the pcap file header or is it done manually(type casting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information are you trying to retrieve from the file header?

You can get the major and minor version with `pcap_major_version()` and `pcap_minor_version()`, the snapshot length with `pcap_snapshot()`, and the link-layer type with `pcap_datalink()`.  There is no guarantee that the time zone offset and time stamp accuracy are valid (libpcap sets both to 0).  Note also that libpcap 1.1.0 and later can read pcap-ng files, which don't *have* a pcap file header.

Libpcap provides no routines to directly hand you the file header, and does not supply anything that you *could* typecast to be a file header, so you *can't* do this with libpcap.  If you want to read the file header, you will have to write your own code to *replace* libpcap, and that code will not be able to handle, for example, pcap-ng files (which will be the default file type in the next release of Wireshark), unlike code that uses libpcap (which can read pcap-ng files, as long as all the network interfaces in the pcap-ng file have the same link-layer header type and snapshot length, when they're using libpcap 1.1.0 or later).

Answer (score 1):

The pcap file header is handled by libpcap internally. You shouldn't have to manipulate it manually.

You can open a pcap file for writing using [`pcap_dump_open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_dump_open).

You can open a pcap file for reading using [`pcap_open_offline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_open_offline).

Comment: if in case I wanted to read the file header then should I type-cast the file handler to the file header structure?  @sander

Comment: @user1192671 : it's a bit more complicated than that (there's a magic number at the start of the file that needs to be interpreted eg.). But you can check the implementation of `pcap_fopen_offline` to see how to read a pcap file header. libpcap is open source after all.